# Options to hide ssid password in an ESP32 sketch

Tags: arduino, esp8266, esp32, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32

I am using `ESP32`, but I assume the question is applicable to `esp8266` or Arduino WIFI. That is why I extended my tags. Please let me know if I am wrong.

I have a working sketch that uses WIFI to send http requests.

My current code includes SSID and password in clear text:

```
const char *ssid = "my_secure_router";
const char *password = "clear_text_password_is_bad";

void initWifi(){
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    Serial.print("*");
  }
  Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
```

While the code is working, I am not able to push the code to a git repository since it includes the password in clear text.

Is there any easy option to eliminate the clear text password from the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People often do this by using a second file that's not checked into the repository. They'll often name the file `secrets.h` or `config.h`.

Then you'd change your code to look like:

```
#include "secrets.h"

void initWifi(){
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.println("");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    Serial.print("*");
  }
  Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
```

and put this in `secrets.h`:

```
#pragma once

#define WIFI_SSID "my_secure_router";
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "clear_text_password_is_bad";
```

The `#pragma` line stops the file from being processed if it's included twice, which avoids errors from `WIFI_SSID` and `WIFI_PASSWORD` being defined multiple times.

Then add `secrets.h` to `.gitignore` so that `git` won't check it in.

As a bonus, you might create a `secrets.h-example` file that has dummy strings for all the secrets that are stored in it.

Note that I changed the two strings from being C++ character array variables to preprocessor constants. There's really no benefit in this case to storing the strings in variables, and using preprocessor constants simplifies their use.

Comment: @AllanXu Arduino Web Editor has support for arduino_secrets.h to not show the content if the sketch is shared. examples of Arduino WiFi libraries use it https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFiNINA/tree/master/examples/WiFiWebClient